# Store random value in C# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on my Unity project. However, I cannot store the random number properly. I just want to store the random number to a variable and use the value later in my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class FloorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material RedGlow;
    public Material OriginColor;
    public Material GreenGlow;

    public GameObject cube0;
    public GameObject cube1;
    public GameObject cube2;
    public GameObject cube3;
    public GameObject cube4;
    public GameObject cube5;
    public GameObject cube6;
    public GameObject cube7;
    public GameObject cube8;

    public GameObject fallcube0;
    public GameObject fallcube1;
    public GameObject fallcube2;
    public GameObject fallcube3;
    public GameObject fallcube4;  
    public GameObject fallcube5;
    public GameObject fallcube6;
    public GameObject fallcube7;
    public GameObject fallcube8;

    // Create Array
    GameObject[] AllCube = new GameObject[9];
    GameObject[] FallCube = new GameObject[9];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Base Cube
        AllCube[0] = cube0;
        AllCube[1] = cube1;
        AllCube[2] = cube2;
        AllCube[3] = cube3;
        AllCube[4] = cube4;
        AllCube[5] = cube5;
        AllCube[6] = cube6;
        AllCube[7] = cube7;
        AllCube[8] = cube8;
        FallCube[0] = fallcube0;
        FallCube[1] = fallcube1;
        FallCube[2] = fallcube2;
        FallCube[3] = fallcube3;
        FallCube[4] = fallcube4;
        FallCube[5] = fallcube5;
        FallCube[6] = fallcube6;
        FallCube[7] = fallcube7;
        FallCube[8] = fallcube8;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            int number = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9);
            int sameNumber = number;
            Debug.Log(number);
            Debug.Log(sameNumber);

            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
            {
                AllCube[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = OriginColor;
                FallCube[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = OriginColor;
            }

            FallCube[number].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = RedGlow;
            AllCube[sameNumber].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = RedGlow;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use the one value directly into 2 objects but failed. It seems that every time I tried to call the random number variable , it random another one again. I have also tried seed value but that is not what I want. I want to generate a random box when getmousebuttondown. The code provided is to test for storing the random number. Please help me to provide a solution or method to get it done. I want the random number in FallCube[] is equal to the number in AllCube[].

Comment: PLEASE post your code as text - screen shots are discouraged!  Yes, you'll get a new random number every time you call "Random()".  And no, if you assign that random value to an "int" variable ... the variable won't change until you do another assignment.  SUGGESTION: try reproducing the problem with a small, self-contained example.

Comment: You say _"I don’t know what is wrong with my code"_. Neither do we. You show a picture of some of your code, but that code does not do much (e.g. you talk about squares, boxes and arrays - but you don't show anything). Refer to the [help] about how to write a good question. Then come up with a [mre] that shows what your problem is

Comment: Sorry for my lack of experience of posting things here(and also my English),  I have fixed what you suggested. Please have a glance of it.

Comment: How do you know these two variables `number` and `sameNumber` have different value? What is the output? Also, have you tested the code you posted? It doesn't seem like it would work.

Comment: regrading your debugging ... `Debug.Log(sameNumber + number);` -> lets says your random `number` was `2` then this will just print `4` .. how do you know they are different now? and `Debug.Log("number")  
        Debug.Log("number")` ... (besides missing `;`) will just print our the word `number` ... Could you post your **actual code** because the one you show us doesn't seem to be it ;)

Comment: with `int number =..` inside your Update method, you are creating a variable that is *local* to the method (read: gone as soon as you exit the method, recreated new when you call the method again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to store `number` variable, but it won't work so, because it's `local` in the snippet you have provided. So every time you do `int number = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9)`, you just create a new variable. I would suggest you to make it not local, for that you have to serialize it somewhere in your class, but not in a method. Although I think it's better to make a method so that you shouldn't change your variable every time.

```cs
private void GetRandomNumber() => UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9);
```

or you can also make a property from it if you also want to access it in another classes.

```cs
public int number => UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9);
```

Comment: Could you please further explain how can I call the method and get the value?

Comment: You call the method just like `GetRandomNumber()` and the value you get just my getting it like normal variable: `number`.
Please, see [C# methods](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_methods.php) and [C# Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: Really sorry, but  I still don't get it. How can I get the random number? Also, do I need to use "private void GetRandomNumber() => UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9);" and "public int number => UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9);" at the same time?

Comment: No, you don't have to use them at the same time. `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9)` returns you random number. So you place it in `int GetRandomNumber` (I have made a typo making it `void` return type). It's `private int GetRandomNumber()`. You have to read more about methods and what they return, Also you have to test it first.

Comment: What result does it get? If you call this method, it returns you random number from 0 to 9 exclusive. What exactly should work but it doesn't?

Comment: Yay, Finally, I get it done by using the above "Method" method and create another variable(using int)(num1) equals the "GetRandomNumber();"  , add create another num2 variable and set num2 = num1. Finally, num2 will equals to num1.  Lot thanks -IDBB for providing me useful info ^^

Comment: I don't really see any reason for you to create 2 variables. You just have to use that method when it's needed. Just make sure not to do redundant things and follow some tutorials or documentations I guess?